# Which Ubuntu distro is right for this 2-in-1?

Tags: xfce, wacom, pantheon

I own a Dell Latitude 11 inch 2-in-1 ... it has a m5-6Y57 processor, 8GB of RAM and 256GB SSD..
Which Ubuntu distro is right for this 2-in-1 ? I want to read ebooks on it so the distro has to support screen rotation and gestures...I also want to take notes with it...The 2-in-1 is Wacom AES enabled and has an active pen.

I guess Ubuntu gnome is the right choice for this laptop...but will it run smooth on this 2-in-1 ? what other distros should i look at ?

---

I also have a Dell inspiron 3179, which has m3-7Y30 processor, 4GB of RAM and 250GB SATA3 SSD ...

Which Ubuntu distro is right for this one ? I am looking at elementary OS and Xubuntu at the moment...Do Xfce and Pantheon support screen rotation and gestures ? i intend to read ebooks on this too...but no note taking as the touchscreen is not AES and doesn't support an active pen.

What other distros do you recommend ?

I know there is Ubuntu Mate and LXQT/DE....but these don't have touchscreen functionalities...

Answer (score 0):

Well, for instance, I don't think you will have any trouble using Ubuntu 18.04 but choice is yours.

Here is the link to 
[Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=latitude&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&level=Any&vendors=Dell)
where you will be able to check that your hardware is supported in several releases.

Then you can check about time supported releases [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

And when you have chosen one and installed it you should check if Synaptic Touchpad is properly installed, a touchpad, and clickpad is a built-in input device for laptops that is used as a computer mouse. Synaptics is a driver for these.

Here is the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) in which you can see how to make sure it work in your Dells.
Yo should be able to configure even sensibility, if you have any further questions, ask its.

I think Ubuntu 18.04 is a good choice, if you choose 18.04 install tweak tool which will help you to enable or disable touch-pad tools and use either keyboard or touch-pads.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am refering to touch screen and not the touchpad....My hardware is compatible with linux ... I want to know if the above mentioned distros perform well with my hardware.

Comment: Well touch screen works in ubuntu 18.04, here is a link where you can see other user experience with a Dell... https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396712